# Why doesn't this MATLAB simulation work?

Tags: matlab

I want to simulate a "game":

start from a deck of n distinct cards, say a vector (1 2 ... n). Separate this in two equally large semidecks, maintaining the initial order; if n is odd, separate it like (1 2 ... (n-1)/2) and ( (n+1)/2 (n+1)/2+1 ... n).

Then mix them so that the farthest down card of the new deck is the farthest down of the first semideck, then put the farthest down of the second semideck, then the second farthest down of the first semideck, and so on. If n is odd one gets:

( (n+1)/2 (n+1)/2+1 1 (n+1)/2+2 2 (n+1)/2+3 3 ... n (n-1)/2).

Then one should repeat this step. The "game" is to find how many iterations are needed to get back to the initial setup (well, assuming it always happens, which seems to be the case). I've written this program but it gets stuck in an infinite loop. What's wrong with it? With no mistakes it should easily return moves=3 for n=3, for example.

```
n=input('How many cards in total?\n');

v=zeros(1,n);

i=1;

moves=0;

for i=1:n
    v(i)=i;
end
w=v;

if mod(n,2)==0

    for i=1:2:n-1
        v(i)=w(n/2+(i+1)/2);
    end

    for i=2:2:n
        v(i)=w(i/2);
    end

    moves=moves+1;

else v(1)=w((n+1)/2);

    for i=3:2:n
        v(i)=w((i-1)/2);
    end

    for i=2:2:n-1
        v(i)=w((n+1)/2+i/2);
    end

    moves=moves+1;
end

tf=isequal(v,w);

while(tf==0)

    if mod(n,2)==0

        for i=1:2:n-1
            v(i)=w(n/2+(i+1)/2);
        end

        for i=2:2:n
            v(i)=w(i/2);
        end

        moves=moves+1;

    else

        v(1)=w((n+1)/2);

        for i=3:2:n
            v(i)=w((i-1)/2);
        end

        for i=2:2:n-1
            v(i)=w((n+1)/2+i/2);
        end

        moves=moves+1;

    end

    tf=isequal(v,w);

end
```

Comment: I suggest you add `disp(v)` after `tf=..` you can see what happens (`v` never changes)

Answer (score 0):

I dont get 100% what you are trying todo, but I think basically you are forgetting to update the "shuffle" deck. You need the previous deck, the current deck, and the objective deck, however you are using the previous and the objective decks as a single variable `w`, but never really updating it.

if you declare a variable `init`, and replace `w` in `tf=isequal(v,init);`, adding an extra line for updating the previous deck, `w=v;` after it, then this code doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.